# css как высчитывается perspective?

Tags: html, css

Я уже замучился понимать математику как считается перспектива..

**Что мне нужно:**

как размеры блока (хоть 1 сторона) зависит от велечины  `perspective : <length>`

**Что я уже узнал:**

1) чтоб работала перспектива, нужно еще указывать и угол поворота, к примеру `transform: rotateY(60deg)`
2) какая ширина блока получится (если не применять перспективу), можно высчитать по косинусу угла, например 60 градусов это 1/2 (или 0,5) блок был 300 пикселей, стал 150; 30 градусов - 0,866... 45 градусов - 0,7...

Вопрос, как математически понять перспективу? на глаз мне не подходит подтягивать все и вся..

P.S. извините, если вопрос упорот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div
{
margin:0; 
padding:0;
border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width:calc(28vw);
height:calc(28vw);
background:transparent;
perspective:700px;
transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.str{
 position:absolute;
 top:calc(100%/4 - 1%);
 left:calc(100%/2 - 10%);
  width: 0px;
  height:calc(5vw);
  border-left:calc(5vw) solid black;
  border-top:calc(5vw) solid transparent;
  border-bottom:calc(5vw) solid transparent;
  border-right: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(110px);
  transition:transform 2s;
}

div:hover .str{
transform: rotateX(360deg) translateZ(110px);
}

.str_1{
 position:absolute;
 top:calc(100%/4 - 1%);
 left:calc(100%/2 - 10%);
  width: 0px;
  height:calc(5vw);
  border-left:calc(5vw) solid black;
  border-top:calc(5vw) solid transparent;
  border-bottom:calc(5vw) solid transparent;
  border-right: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(110px);
  transition:transform 2s;
}

div:hover .str_1{
transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(110px);
}

.str_3{
 position:absolute;
 top:calc(100%/4 - 1%);
 left:calc(100%/2 - 10%);
  width: 0px;
  height:calc(5vw);
  border-left:calc(5vw) solid black;
  border-top:calc(5vw) solid transparent;
  border-bottom:calc(5vw) solid transparent;
  border-right: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  transform:  skewY(0deg) translate(0px) ;
  transition:transform 2s;
}

div:hover .str_3{
transform:  skewY(360deg) translate(10px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="str"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="str_1"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="str_3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какая функциональность нужна вашей трапеции? какие действия от неё требуются? или нужна адаптивность  (резиновый_макет)?

Comment: Сейчас она резиновая...

Comment: Спасибо, достаточно! ты лучший!!!! =) удивляюсь то на сколько ты развернуто решил ответить на вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```css
@keyframes _img{
0%{
-webkit-transform:rotateX(-360deg) translateZ(100px) rotateX(360deg);
transform:rotateX(-360deg) translateZ(100px) rotateX(360deg);
}
100%{
-webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg) translateZ(100px) rotateX(0deg);
transform:rotateX(0deg) translateZ(100px) rotateX(0deg);
}
}
div
{ 
border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
display:block;
position: relative;
width:calc(60vw);
height:calc(20vw);
margin:0% auto;
background:hsla(0,0%,60%,1);
box-shadow:inset .75em .75em .75em hsla(0,0%,100%,1),inset -.75em -.75em .75em hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
perspective:700px;
transform-style:preserve-3d;
transition:all 1s linear 0s;
}
img {
border-radius: 50%;
border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,60%,1);
position:absolute;
width:calc(8vw);
height:calc(8vw);
top:calc(100%/3 - 3%);
left:calc(100%/2 - 10%);
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px  hsla(70,80%,40%,1));
-webkit-transform:rotateX(0deg) translateZ(160px) rotateX(0deg);
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px  hsla(70,80%,40%,1));
transform:rotateX(0deg) translateZ(160px) rotateX(0deg);
}
div:hover img{
 animation:_img 3s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Рабочий пример ... Наведите мышку для просмотра , срабатывает на hover.... Не разберётесь как работает напишите...

Comment: Или свой пример что именно хотите сделать?

Comment: Вы написали perspective:700px; это величина от куда до куда?

Comment: Перспектива это иллюзия глубины, по русски_берёт зеркало смотрим в него и сзади себя видим на стене картину если будем отходить картина уменьшается и наоборот подходим увеличивается , вот это расстояние между вами и картиной есть эти 700px  . В примере от зависимости сколько ставите это значение картинка увеличивается или уменьшается. В нашем случае это иллюзия глубины монитора. Поставьте 300px картинка увеличиться и наоборот . Что не поняли спрашивайте..

Comment: Мне конечно примерно понятно.. но когда нужно сделать фигуру по определенным размерам, получается, что ничего не понятно. вот мне нужно сделать c помощью перспективы такую трапецию `<div style="width: 0px; height: 10px; border-left: 15px solid black; border-top: 15px solid transparent; border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;"></div>` но на выходе получается, что подбирать величины?